# sorting an array by it's values

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array like :

```
var myArray = [5, 0, 2, 8, 11, 1000, 50];
```

**Can I sort it to get an array or numbers from the biggest number to the lowest one?**, like this :

```
// [1000, 50, 11, 8, 5, 2, 0]
```

Comment: I believe you didn't try searching it. There are so many resources talking about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Sort alphabetically and ascending:
var myArray = [5, 0, 2, 8, 11, 1000, 50];
myarray.sort();

//Sort alphabetically and descending:
var myArray = [5, 0, 2, 8, 11, 1000, 50];
myarray.sort();
myarray.reverse();

// Sort numerically decending order:
myArray = myArray.sort(function(a, b) {return b - a;});
```

Comment: original array : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... 30.. after.sort and reverse() => 9,8,7,6,5,4,30,3,29,27,26,25,24...10,1

Comment: Notice that it's comparing the values lexicographically.

Comment: Yes just noticed this. Answer amended. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, with the : sort(function(a, b) { return b-a }), it gives the right result.

Comment: @John - Cool. Sorry for initial mix up. I got excited that I knew this one and didn't fully think it over.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
var myArray = [5, 0, 2, 8, 11, 1000, 50];
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
});
```

as suggested here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yes by using **reverse** method. **Sort** method would sort it in ascending order.

```
var myArray = [5, 0, 2, 8, 11, 1000, 50]; 

myArray.reverse();
```

For more operation on Array, look at this [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml)

Comment: this would produce the array `[50, 1000, 11, 8, 2, 0, 5]`, so not what he asked for. I think you're missing a call to sort, it should be `myArray.sort().reverse()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sort()` function.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Note that the default behaviour of `sort()` is **alphabetically ascending**.  To sort in **numerical descending** order you will need to pass a compare function, e.g.

```
var myArray = [5, 0, 2, 8, 11, 1000, 50];
myArray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this is simple :

```
 myArray.sort()
```

Comment: This would sort in ascending. He wants in descending order

Comment: do not use both sort and reverse. Either one of them

Comment: did you try this                                 myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b > a;
});

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
myarray.sort(function(a,b){return b - a})
```